# C# Json Deserialize returns nulls

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, serialization

So I have a JSON saved in a file, let's say test.json. I'm opening the file, read the JSON inside it in a string and then I'm trying to deserialize it into an object. The file is opened right, the string is read (but escapes appear in string) and when I try to deserialize it it returns nulls for all fields of object and I can't understand why.

Here is how JSON is saved in file: http://pastebin.com/Q6hdiJAD

Here is how JSON is saved in my string after being read from file: http://pastebin.com/HaB480Ww

Here is the code that should deserialize JSON (I'm taking multiple jsons from multiple files and deserialize them and add them to list):

```
List<Root> raw = new List<Root>();    
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/Files"));
                foreach (string path in files)
                {
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
                    {
                        string json = sr.ReadToEnd();
                        Root root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
                        raw.Add(root);
                    }
                }
```

And here is my class:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using APIGovApp.Models;

namespace APIGovApp.Classes
{
    public class XmlModel
    {
        public string Staff { get; set; }
        public List<Nomenclator> noms { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public XmlModel nom_localitati { get; set; }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace APIGovApp.Models
{
    public class Nomenclator
    {
        public int cod_jud { get; set; }
        public int cod { get; set; }
        public int cod_pol { get; set; }
        public string denumire { get; set; }
        public string cod_tpl { get; set; }
        public int cod_postal { get; set; }
        public string cod_sar { get; set; }
        public int cod_loc_jud { get; set; }
        public int loc_cod { get; set; }
        public string are_primarie { get; set; }
        public int cod_fiscal_primarie { get; set; }
        public int cod_politie_tata { get; set; }
        public string sar_cod_mf { get; set; }
        public int cod_siruta { get; set; }
        public int cod_siruta_tata { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I'm participating in a contest and I need this as fast as possible. Please help.

Comment: The names in your `Nomenclator` don't match the JSON, for instance `cod_jud` instead of `JUD_COD`.  Upload your JSON to http://json2csharp.com/ to auto-generate a correct set of classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like the names of list properties don't match.

In code:

```
public List<Nomenclator> noms { get; set; }
```

In file:

```
{"NOM_LOCALITATI":{"Staff":null,"rand":
```

Notice the noms vs. rand

Rename noms to rand or give the parser a hint by adding the following attribute:

```
 [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "rand")]
 public List<Nomenclator> noms { get; set; }
```

Comment: Should I also modify fields inside Nomenclator class to match the tags inside every "rand"?

Comment: I think JsonConvert tries case sensitive first and then case insensitive so it should work unless the names are not the same in which case you would have to do the same for those.